# Inner Selection, Sum of colunms with conditions order by Region

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

After selection I get my new clear table like

```
     SELECT a.sta_name, a.product, a.product_id, a.date, a.active, a.region_id, a.brand, a.brand_id  from
        (SELECT DISTINCT sta_name, product, product_id, date, active, region_id, brand, brand_id FROM `sv_ziyaret` 
        WHERE brand_id=2 and date between "2021-07-00" and "2021-07-31" order by region_id) a
```

so I get my values `DISTINCT`

```
sta_name | product | product_id | active | region_id | brand | brand_id| date |
3M         A            1          1          1          A1       1     2021-07-02
2M         A            1          0          1          A1       1     2021-07-02
5M         B            2          0          1          A1       1     2021-07-05
4M         B            2          0          2          A1       1     2021-07-06
M          A            2          1          2          A1       1     2021-07-10
2M         C            3          1          4          A1       1     2021-07-12
3M         B            2          1          4          A1       1     2021-07-15
```

**`sta_name` never repeats with same `region_id`, `products` do.** What I try to get is

```
product_id | product | active_on | active_off | region_id
1             A           12           2            1
1             A            7           9            2
2             B            6          10            1
2             B           16           5            2
3             C           10           5            4
```

My main purpose is to be able to calculate percentage of product's existance in each region. In instance A product has %80 on sale on shalves at region A.

Manualy I am able to get each products result as

```
SELECT 
    product, product_id, region_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sv_ziyaret.active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) var, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN sv_ziyaret.active = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yok 
FROM 
    `sv_ziyaret` 
WHERE 
  product_id=37 and date between "2021-07-00"  and "2021-07-31" and region_id=7 order by region_id
```

but this is not a good solution I need it to be able to get each product by giving its `brand_id` only.
Hope to get a hand realy would same my weak

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the general solution. You just need GROUP BY AND [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day).

```sql
SELECT 
    product, product_id, region_id, LAST_DAY(date) month_ending,
    SUM(CASE WHEN sv_ziyaret.active = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) var, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN sv_ziyaret.active = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) yok 
FROM 
    sv_ziyaret
WHERE 
GROUP BY product, product_id, region_id, LAST_DAY(date)  
ORDER BY region_id, LAST_DAY(date), product_id;
```